# Seperate NSDecimalNumber in 2 points after dot ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am building an iOS app which is using webservice to get data. I am getting `sum` value in `NSDecimalNumber` in a format like "1.123456789". I want to show only 2 points after dot i.e: "1.12".

How is this possible?

Comment: Please add the relevant code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSDecimalNumber *sum = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1.123456789"]; //Which you already have

NSDecimalNumberHandler *handler =[NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:NSRoundPlain
                                                                                            scale:2 // change this to change the precision
                                                                                 raiseOnExactness:NO
                                                                                  raiseOnOverflow:NO
                                                                                 raiseOnUnderflow:NO
                                                                              raiseOnDivideByZero:NO];

NSDecimalNumber *result = [sum decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:handler];
NSLog(@"%@", result); //Here is your desire result
```